# What is the explanation for this expression in bash: (($a<0?10:$a<100))?

Tags: bash

```
a=10
b=$(($a<0?10:$a<100))
echo $b
```

I don't understand the second line. Why does it evaluate to 1?

Comment: BTW: The second line could be written simpler, as `((b = a<0 ? 10 :  a<100 ))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(( ... ))` is an *arithmetic expansion* [[link](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)]: the `...` part is evaluated as shell arithmetic, and the result of that evaluation is substituted.

In shell arithmetic:

- `condition ? result_if_condition_is_nonzero : result_if_condition_is_zero` evaluates to `result_if_condition_is_nonzero` if `condition` is nonzero (meaning "true" in shell arithmetic), and otherwise to `result_if_condition_is_zero`.
- `value1 < value2` evaluates to 1 ("true") if `value1` is less than `value2`; otherwise, it evaluates to 0 ("false").

So, if `$a` is an integer (which in your case it is), then

```
b=$(( ($a < 0) ? 10 : ($a < 100 ? 1 : 0) ))
```

means "if `a` is less than 0, then set `b=10`; otherwise, if `a` is less than 100, then set `b=1`; otherwise set `b=0`; and

```
b=$(($a<0?10:$a<100))
```

means the same thing, plus a strong subtext of "I'd rather that no one ever try to read my code, and if they do, I'll make sure it's a mistake they won't make twice."

Answer (score 1):

The form `expr1?expr2:expr3` is allowed in arithmetic expansion and functions as an `if` statement.  If `expr1` evaluates to non-zero (true), then `expr2` is returned.  If zero (false), then `expr3` is returned.  For example:

```
$ a=1; echo $((a?10+2:10+3))
12
$ a=0; echo $((a?10+2:10+3))
13
```

On your case, if `$a<0` is true (a is negative), then 10 is returned.  Otherwise (a is zero or positive), then the truth value of `$a<100` is returned.

```
$ a=-1; echo $(($a<0?10:$a<100))
10
$ a=99; echo $(($a<0?10:$a<100))
1
$ a=101; echo $(($a<0?10:$a<100))
0
```